# Convert csv to a table in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

**I have a csv in the format below that needs to be converted to json or a table so that I can parse it easily and use the values as arguments later in my code**

```
Directory     : \\foo\foofoo\nightly.188\share\name
Name          : name.pst
Length        : 271360
CreationTime  : 6/4/2009 2:42:21 PM
LastWriteTime : 6/9/2011 8:58:50 AM

Directory     : \\foo\foofoo\nightly.188\share\name
Name          : name2.pst
Length        : 71123968
CreationTime  : 10/5/2010 2:41:56 PM
LastWriteTime : 8/1/2011 4:08:32 PM
```

I have tried using Format-List and Format-Table but does not help.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

I would like the output to be in a tabular structure as:

Directory                            Name        Length      CreationTime             LastWriteTime
\foo\foofoo\nightly.188\share\name  name.pst    271360      6/4/2009 2:42:21 PM     8/1/2011 4:08:32 PM
\foo\foofoo\nightly.188\share\name  name2.pst   71123968    10/5/2010 2:41:56 PM    8/1/2011 4:08:32 PM

Comment: _"I have tried"_ -- Please edit the question to add the code of what you have tried. Otherwise people can only guess what is wrong (some people may even assume that you actually didn't try anything).

Comment: The _format below_ doesn't show anything resembling a CSV format. At best, this is the output from `Import-Csv -Path 'theFile.csv | Format-List'`

Answer (score 1):

To view CSV data to the console as a table do the following

```
$sorceFile = "D:\temp\source.csv"
Import-Csv $sorceFile | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You can also use the "Out-GridView" command if you want to view the data interactively

```
$sorceFile = "D:\temp\source.csv"
Import-Csv $sorceFile | Out-GridView
```

The following converts CSV data to Json data

```
$sorceFile = "D:\temp\source.csv"
$JsonData = Import-Csv $sorceFile | ConvertTo-Json
$JsonData
```

This however is just a string. If you are wanting to process the data further from the CSV file then do the following to save to a variable.

```
$sorceFile = "D:\temp\source.csv"
$CsvData= Import-Csv $sorceFile

# view formatted table in console
$CsvData | format-table

#example data query 
$CsvData | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'name.pst'}

#example loop
foreach ($row in $CsvData) {
    Write-Output "Name: $($row.name) CreationTime: $(get-date $row.CreationTime -Format 'dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K')"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Format-List and Format-table convert your data into a form that's suitable for display on your console, or copying into a text file.  This is useful for parsing, but not for passing the data on as arguments.  If you just do an import like this:

```
Import-Csv myfile.csv
```

Powershell will do an implicit Format-Table or Format-List for you before putting it on your console.

If you want to use the contents as arguments,  be aware that the contents of a csv file are transformed into an array of PSCustomObject.  Each PSCustomObject has properties with the same name as a the field name provided in the header of the CSV file.

```
Import-Csv thefile.csv | % {
    "The file $($_.name) contains:"
    Get-Content $_.name
}
```